# Div vs Span html tags

Tags: html, performance

In my application, i have to display a huge treeview with more than 10,000 nodes. I have made a custom control to do this but wanted to know which tag to use div or span to apply formatting and which is faster also on IE8. I used div and the page reder took 17 sec. Should i use span ? Or any other way to improve page performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a tag, that matches the meaning of the content—for a **list** of files and folders a **list** would be appropriate. You may nest multiple `UL`s to present your tree.

The parsing speed doesn't have to do with the tag you used, but rather with the CSS you wrote (and a lot of others reasons). See also: [How do you measure page load speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240333/how-do-you-measure-page-load-speed)

Answer (score -4):

Span would be more ideal I would say, with regards to page optimisation, you may have to have a look at some javascript to maybe alter things to increase performance.

Comment: The HTML tags generally have no noticeable effect on the page's render speed. He should be using the semantically correct element, which are `ul`s and `li`s.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha div and span are don't have semantic meaning. I'd go for `div` for performance because it's 1 character shorter. `:D`